# how to get custom directive scope outside the ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

My **HTML** code

```
<div ng-repeat="jump in counter track by $index" >
     <spinner jump="result1" ></spinner>
   <span>{{$index+1}}_spinner value:- {{result1}}</span>
 </div>
```

my **controller**:

```
$scope.counter = [0,1,2];
```

`<spinner>` is a custom directive, by 'jump' i'm isolating the scope

I want the scope of each spinners in outside the ng-repeat with another ng-repeat, to display each spinner's value.

You can view my example on a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KPHqes1baju70oSYRdRp?p=preview) I created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of object as model for your `ng-repeat` as:

```
$scope.spinners = [{id: 0, value: 0},{id: 1, value: 0},{id: 2, value: 0}];
```

and in HTML:

```
<b>inside ng-repeat</b>
<div ng-repeat="spinner in spinners track by $index">
  <spinner jump="spinner.value"></spinner>
  <span>{{$index+1}}_spinner value:- {{spinner.value}}</span>
</div>

<b>out</b>
<div ng-repeat="spinner in spinners track by $index">
  <span>{{$index+1}}_spinner value:- {{spinner.value}}</span>
</div>
```

Check the modified Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/TILKLELHMZDhSLAPj2fp?p=preview

Comment: If the answer was useful for you please [accept it and vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it